# Kodi crashing in 16.04LTS after installing updates

Tags: kodi

Kodi fails to launch after Ubuntu updates. Deleted and reinstalled a number of time without any success. Crash log shows 3 errors. All help appreciated. Crash Log:

```
############## Kodi CRASH LOG ###############

################ SYSTEM INFO ################
 Date: Fri 17 Feb 22:27:00 GMT 2017
 Kodi Options: 
 Arch: x86_64url:
 Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017
 Release: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
############## END SYSTEM INFO ##############

############### STACK TRACE #################
=====>  Core file: /home/john/core (2017-02-17 22:27:00.988895510 +0000)
        =========================================
[New LWP 6741]
[New LWP 6742]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi/kodi.bin'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f69f0980428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f69f7e16980 (LWP 6741))]

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f69db8db700 (LWP 6742)):
#0  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:143
#1  0x000000000144d5b1 in ANNOUNCEMENT::CAnnouncementManager::Process() ()
#2  0x0000000000d0a215 in CThread::Action() ()
#3  0x0000000000d0a46f in CThread::staticThread(void*) ()
#4  0x00007f69f7afd6ba in start_thread (arg=0x7f69db8db700) at pthread_create.c:333
#5  0x00007f69f0a5182d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f69f7e16980 (LWP 6741)):
#0  0x00007f69f0980428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007f69f098202a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89url:
#2  0x00007f69f0fb984d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007f69f0fb76b6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007f69f0fb7701 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f69f0fb7919 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x0000000000f14059 in dbiplus::SqliteDataset::query(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#7  0x0000000000efdd14 in CDatabase::GetDBfile:///home/john/kodi_crashlog-20170217_222700.logVersion() ()
#8  0x000000000103b9ab in CDatabaseManager::Initialize(bool) ()
#9  0x0000000001007683 in CApplication::Create() ()
#10 0x0000000000d3bcdc in XBMC_Run ()
#11 0x00000000007ff2eb in main ()
############# END STACK TRACE ###############

################# LOG FILE ##################

22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://profile/ is mapped to: special://masterprofile/
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Starting Kodi (17.0 Git:20170210-nogitfound). Platform: Linux x86 64-bit
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Using Release Kodi x64 build
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Kodi compiled Nov  4 2012 by GCC 5.4.0 for Linux x86 64-bit version 4.4.40 (263208)
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, kernel: Linux x86 64-bit version 4.4.0-62-generic
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: FFmpeg version/source: ffmpeg-3.1-kodi
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Host CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 4 cores available
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://xbmc/ is mapped to: /usr/share/kodi
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://xbmcbin/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://xbmcbinaddons/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi/addons
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /home/john/.kodi/userdata
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://envhome/ is mapped to: /home/john
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://home/ is mapped to: /home/john/.kodi
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://temp/ is mapped to: /home/john/.kodi/temp
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://logpath/ is mapped to: /home/john/.kodi/temp
22:27:00.840 T:14009url:3107038592  NOTICE: The executable running is: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi/kodi.bin
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Local hostname: john-MS-7816
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Log File is located: /home/john/.kodi/temp//kodi.log
22:27:00.840 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
22:27:00.855 T:140093107038592   ERROR: DBus: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs - No such property 'CanSuspend'
22:27:00.855 T:140093107038592   ERROR: DBus: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs - No such property 'CanHibernate'
22:27:00.855 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: load settings...
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Found 1 Lists of Devices
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Enumerated PULSE devices:
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:     Device 1
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : Defaultfile:///home/john/kodi_crashlog-20170217_222700.log
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Default
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: Default Output Device (PULSEAUDIO)
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_streamTypes     : No passthrough capabilities
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:     Device 2
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-21
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Built-in Audio Analogue Surround 2.1
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: Line Out (PULSEAUDIO)
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR,LFE
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_streamTypes     : No passthrough capabilities
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:     Device 3
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.1.hdmi-stereo
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series] Digital Stereo (HDMI)
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: HDMI / DisplayPort (PULSEAUDIO)
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
22:27:00.862 T:140093107038592  NOTICE:         m_streamTypes     : No passthrough capabilities
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://xbmc/system/advancedsettings.xml)
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://masterprofile/advancedsettings.xml)
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Default Video Player: VideoPlayer
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Default Audio Player: paplayer
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Disabled debug logging due to GUI setting. Level 0.
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Log level changed to "LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL"
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: CMediaSourceSettings: loading media sources from special://masterprofile/sources.xml
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://xbmc/system/playercorefactory.xml.
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Loaded playercorefactory configuration
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml.
22:27:00.864 T:140093107038592  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml does not exist. Skipping.
22:27:00.866 T:140093107038592   ERROR: SQL: [Addons27.db] SQL error or missing database
                                            Query: SELECT idVersion FROM version


############### END LOG FILE ################

############ END Kodi CRASH LOG #############
```

Regards,

John

Comment: You might either reinstall Kodi 17.0, or downgrade to Kodi 16.1.

Comment: You could post this trace in kodi.tv forums or search for similar problems over there. Of this really is due to Ubuntu updates it is likely you are not the only one with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will follow up on your advice. John

Comment: Any hints? I tried both kodi version include din ubuntu and the official kodi distro and both are crashing on start.

Answer (score 0):

Move or remove `~/.kodi/Database/Addons27.db`, start Kodi, and wait for the addons database to be rebuilt.